# Drawing two different shapes overwrites one another [Core Profile OpenGL]

Tags: c++, opengl

So I have created a class that helps me abstract a lot of the drawing process when it comes to making basic shapes for prototyping shaders.

This class, named Geometry.h works great for drawing just one object, however upon adding a second object like so:

```cpp
// Main Render Loop
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.Zoom), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
        cube.shader.setMat4("projection", projection);
        cube.shader.setMat4("view", view);
        plane.shader.setMat4("view", view);
        plane.shader.setMat4("projection", projection);


        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        cube.shader.setMat4("model", model);
        cube.shader.setFloat("time", currentFrame);
        cube.Draw();

        model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(2.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f));
        plane.shader.setMat4("model", model);
        plane.shader.setFloat("time", currentFrame);
        plane.Draw();
```

"cube" and "plane" are both models of the same set of vertices, one is just going to be scaled in a way to remove the y-axis and make it a plane. The issue is, when I draw these, only the former gets drawn and it gets drawn with the shader of the latter.

Here is the relevant code of my `Geometry` class

```cpp
// Geometry.h
class Geometry {
public:
    std::vector<float> mesh;
    std::vector<GLuint> indices;
    GLuint VAO;
    Shader shader;

    Geometry(std::vector<float> vertices, std::vector<GLuint> indices);
    void Draw();
    void setShader(const char* vs, const char* fs);

private:
    GLuint VBO, EBO;

    void setup();

};
```

```cpp
// Geometry.cpp
void Geometry::Draw()
{
    shader.use();
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

// Called in constructor[![enter image description here][1]][1]
void Geometry::setup()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.size() * sizeof(float), &mesh[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

We currently are getting a result like such: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9peMn.jpg), which shows it is using the planes shader because the cubes shader has a color based on position. Where the planes shader is using a constant white color in its fragment shader.

Comment: Side note (doesn't solve the issue): The [index buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) (the buffer which is bound to the target `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`) is stated in the VAO, hence delete `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);`. Furthermore it is sufficient to bind `glBindVertexArray(VAO);` when drawing the geometry (you don't need to bind `VBO` and `IBO`).

Comment: Awesome, I cleaned up those parts of the code thanks for letting me know @Rabbid76

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`glUniform`*](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) sets a uniform in the default uniform block of the current program, thus the program has to be installed before, by [`glUseProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml):

```cpp
cube.shader.use(); // <----- install program
cube.shader.setMat4("projection", projection);
cube.shader.setMat4("view", view);
cube.shader.setMat4("model", model);
cube.shader.setFloat("time", currentFrame);
cube.Draw();
```

```cpp
plane.shader.use(); // <----- install program
plane.shader.setMat4("view", view);
plane.shader.setMat4("projection", projection);
plane.shader.setMat4("model", model);
plane.shader.setFloat("time", currentFrame);
plane.Draw();
```

Comment: Ah! Okay that actually makes a lot of sense. (Really erring on the side of a duh moment lol)